# Multiple Permission Layers in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently working on a project dashboard in Excel, and I need to have two tiers of access:
- Layer 1: Admin. This is o password protect all the cells that users shouldn't be touching. Layer 2: Project Manager this is to make certain ranges editable to the project managers who have the password for that specific sheet.

Essentially I want to lock the sheet but have an additional password to unlock just a few cells on the sheet.

Is this possible? I've looked around on here and with Google searches, but have found nothing useful.

Thanks for your time!
Joel

Comment: I'm terrible with VBA, I've only been messing with the Protect Sheet, Protect Workbook, and Allow Users to Edit Ranges functionalities. I'm assuming the answer lies within VBA; I just don't know where to start. With a nudge in the right direction I'm sure I could figure it out.

Comment: That is the right way. I would do something around protecting. You will need to make sure that the cells you want to allow Layer2 to be able to edit either locked or unlocked and then protect the sheet so you can only click either locked or unlocked. That way all of the other cells will not be able to edit apart from ones you specify

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get started (and one with a very cut and dry, Admin vs. PM approach) involves protecting the whole sheet (and keeping it protected), yet unlocking permissible ranges selectively. The caveat here: all of the sheet cells must be fully locked on `Workbook_Open`. This can be done using Workbook events (if you need help there, please ask).

In the code I'm sharing below, there are a few items to note. `rngAdmin` refers to the cells to which an admin should have access. Likewise, `rngProjectManager` refers to the cell to which a PM should have access. `sSheetPassword` is the actual sheet password, as setup in the `Protect Sheet` Excel feature. The other two passwords reside only in our module. Obviously, all of these should be changed to something more secure.

If an admin password is entered, the admin range is unlocked. If the PM password is entered, the PM range is unlocked. If the incorrect password is entered, the sheet is read only. Thoughts?

```
Sub MultipleLayersofProtection()
    Dim rngAdmin As Range
    Dim rngProjectManager As Range
    Dim sUserEnteredPW As String

    Const sSheetPassword = "yupyupyup"
    Const sAdminPW As String = "ABC123"
    Const sProjectManagerPW As String = "LMNOP"


    Set rngAdmin = Sheet1.Range("A1:C50")
    Set rngProjectManager = Union(Sheet1.Range("A1:A5"), Sheet1.Range("C1:C5"))

    sUserEnteredPW = Application.InputBox("Please enter the password:", , , , , , , 2)

    Select Case sUserEnteredPW
        Case sAdminPW
            Sheet1.Unprotect Password:=sSheetPassword
            rngAdmin.Locked = False
            Sheet1.Protect Password:=sSheetPassword
            MsgBox ("Admin Access")
        Case sProjectManagerPW
            Sheet1.Unprotect Password:=sSheetPassword
            rngProjectManager.Locked = False
            Sheet1.Protect Password:=sSheetPassword
            MsgBox ("PM Access")
        Case Else
            MsgBox ("Read only access")
    End Select


End Sub
```